# Prove that the subset of R, I, is an interval if and only if I contains at least 2 points and for all a,c in I, and b in R, we have b in I

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question in my real analysis assignment, and it is also a proposition in the textbook without proof. The complete question is the following:
A set $I \subset R$ is an interval if and only if $I$ contains at least 2 points and for all $a,c \in I$ and $b \in R$ such that $a < b <c$, we have $b \in I$.

I'm thinking about proving this through contradiction, assuming that there are less than 2 points for some I.

However, I do not have a complete solution for this without knowing what definitions of the interval I can use. Can anyone share some ideas ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I presume you are relatively new to proof-writing; for $A \iff B$, you might individually assume $A$, then prove $B$, and conversely assume $B$ then prove $A$ to complete the proof. I think with your book's definitions in mind this becomes fairly clear; in general, you might think about the interval $(a,a)$, $(a,a]$, etc. as some possible issues, but you shouldn't worry about that for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will have to look up how your textbook defines "interval". As Snared has already demonstrated, you cannot expect others to use the exact same definition. It should have this thing in the back called an "index". In it, you can look up the entry for "interval", and it will have a list of page numbers. Probably intervals will be defined on the first of those pages, or very shortly afterwards. But if they are not, try the second page number listed, and so on. It is extremely unlikely that your book did not provide a definition of "interval" to be used for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The if is trivial since it is the definition of an interval. For proving the only if, Let $a, a' \in I$, $a \neq a'$. Let $b \in \mathbb R$ and $a<b<a'$ where $b \not \in I$. $I$ is not path connected and hence not an interval. Proof by contradiction as you stated! Hence the iff is true.